# Cannot access Spring Boot Web via localport on browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've just entered my 2nd semester of Comp Sci and we've started to learn about spring boot. The very very basics. So far, we've learned how to create the page and access via localhost:8080 and also how to change the port to 9090.

For some reason, I cannot access the page via localhost:**** with **** being the port number when it is typed directly into my browser. I can access it via IntelliJ's browser buttons that it provides, but it changes the port to a random one like 63663 or something like that. I asked my professor and he didn't know what was going on either and I can't seem to find a solution online. https://gyazo.com/6763b9aa1fd06911ab4e95a861ad920c - This is the error I get.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are developing rest API project then in @GetMapping put a / and return some data
`@GetMapping("/")
public <return_type> yourMethodName(){
//// Operation

return <Object of the return type>

}`
404 means resource not found

Comment: that is an 404 error, so the port is correct (the web container is answering that 404). It is not finding a correct URL (path)

Comment: So how do I fix that? I'm aware of what a 404 error is, but I followed along with the professor exactly as he did, and it works if I access it via the IDE

Comment: please add the bootrstrap.yml / application.yml (or properties files) so that we can see what is going on.
Also like stated above, in the add a @controller with  @GetMapping("/")  function that returns hello world string,
One last thing, make sure you have "/" at the end of the URL, example:
http://localhost:9090/